# Wordpress presenting errors when editing webpage using elementor and also getting errors at the admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

thanks for the help.
When editing a page I'm getting these errors:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'pro_widgets' in
> /home/zzz/xxx/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/api.php
> on line 161
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in
> /home/zzz/xxx/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/api.php
> on line 161
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'pro_widgets' in
> /home/zzz/xxx/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/api.php
> on line 164
>
> Deprecated: jquery-slick is deprecated since version 2.7.0! Use Swiper
> instead. in /home/zzz/xxx/wp-includes/functions.php
> on line 5401

Also, at the admin panel I'm getting this error:

> Notice: WP_Scripts::localize was called incorrectly. The $l10n
> parameter must be an array. To pass arbitrary data to scripts, use the
> wp_add_inline_script() function instead. Read How to Debug WordPress
> for more information. (This message was added in version 5.7.0.) in
> /home/zzz/xxx/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5663

How can I fix this?

I use elementor plugin and JUpiterX theme.

Thanks!!!